# Bloquear botón secundario con javascript

Tags: javascript, botón, teclado

Pues la verdad, no es tan sencillo como lo indica el titulo de mi pregunta, bloquear el botón secundario es sencillo y ese código ya lo tengo, ahora lo que quiero hacer el bloquear el botón secundario pero desde el teclado, para los que no lo sepan en el teclado existe una tecla que actúa como botón secundario.

Este es un boton secundario en un teclado. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, alguien sabe como puedo bloquear específicamente esa tecla con javascript?

Quedo atento, gracias

Comment: Hola pon un observador para eventos que atrape keyPress o keyUp y envía a consola el código de la tecla keyCode. Así sabrás el valor que debes bloquear usando event.preventDefault().

Comment: Si ya me fije, no lo sabia, en esta web https://tutorialesenlinea.es/Editor/jquery-3.html, al presionar una tecla te dice cual es el código de la misma, es muy util.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo tienes que asignar el evento [keyup](https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/event_onkeyup.asp) a tu elemento que quieres evitar que se ejecute el evento, validar el keyCode de la tecla que se presiono y cancelarlo.

```
document.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 93) { // key ContextMenu
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

```js
//Lo añado a todo el document, para evitar que en algun input se pueda ejecutar, pero puede ir directo a cualquier elemento
document.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 93) { // key: "ContextMenu"
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="ejemplo">
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto @eduardo Jaramillo, gracias por tu ayuda, ahora se que cada tecla tiene un codigo en el teclado, modifique un poco tu codigo par que muestre un mensaje al presionar la tecla.  document.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 93) { alert(' Alerta!\n Tecla de función deshabilitada.');
    }
 { event.preventDefault();}
 });